USB powered board using the FT230X
I am designing my first board using an STM32G0B0 MCU and want to use the FT230X for serial USB communication. In the data sheet of the FT230X I have read about 'BUS powered' and 'self powered'. What I think I need, is BUS powered since I want to use the USB for power and data.
For that, the FT230X takes the 5V VBUS as VCC and outputs 3.3V at 3V3OUT but only at 50mA.
From the data sheet:

The main function of the LDO is to power the USB Transceiver and the Reset Generator Cells
rather than to power external logic. However, it can be used to supply external circuitry requiring a
+3.3V nominal supply with a maximum current of 50mA.

To me, this it seems like this wont be enough voltage to power the rest of the board.
My solution would be to build an external LDO and feed the 3.3V into the VCC of the FT230X.
Is this a viable solution?
How is this done normally?

The G0B0 has native support for USB. Why do you want to add a FT230X to add USB to a MCU that already has USB? Of course you might have reasons to do so, I just want to verify if you really want to do that. The G0B0 is also very limited in power consumption so it is hard to make it consume past 15mA. The board of course may have other stuff that makes it above 50mA.

@Justme My problem is, that I use the STM32G0B0KET6 and from the data sheet "The HSE crystal oscillator is not available on 32-pin packages. The precise clock for the USB peripheral must be provided
by some other means.". This means I would need an external cristal to use USB. But the 32 pin package only has OSC_IN on pin PC14 but no OSC_OUT. This is why I thought that this chip does not directly support USB.

True, you need to feed in a square wave clock from a separate crystal oscillator via one pin only. Bigger case supports crystal directly. G0B1 models support crystal-less USB device mode. But if you don't have a crystal at all, you still need a somewhat reliable timebase for UART. HSI with calibration to UART reception can do it. But which one is cheaper, add the $2 FTDI chip, or use the $1 for better MCU and crystal?

@Justme So it would be possible to ditch the FT230 and connect a crystal oscillator ic to pc14?

That's how many/most ST eval boards with onboard ST-Link work - they have no crystal for the target MCU, the ST-Link debugger MCU has a crystal and feeds 8 MHz to target MCU.

Yes, things powered only via USB cord (like keyboards and mice) are bus-powered. Other devices with their own power supply (like printers) are self-powered.
If the 50mA provided by FTDI IC is not enough then you need an external regulator to convert 5V to 3.3V. Also note that the MCU itself will not draw 50mA, but you may have other power consuming items onboard.
Also realize that your USB device must not draw more than 100mA total, unless you have configured the FTDI IC to request more from the host PC and signals to your circuitry that it's OK to draw more than 100mA and up to the requested current. The device needs to be able to keep consumption below 100mA until properly enumerated.
External LDO or switch mode buck converter are viable solutions.
